# Using a Tuple of Tuples Template

Tags: python, python-3.x, tuples

I have a script that makes a DB call then returns the results as a tuple of tuples. The DB call tracks data from a year-to-data, month-to-date, and week-to-date format.

Because of the new fiscal year I am no longer getting any Year-to-date data for some items, as expected, but I need to create an entry in the tuple if the DB didn't return anything so the final table will display all locations and write a zero if nothing returned.

Here is what I have:

```
def Main():
    template = (('ham', '0905', 0), ('Wind', '852', 0), ('Wash', '3292', 0), ('Chitt', '3367', 0))
    yr = sql_fin('year')
    yr = db_query(yr)  # Yearly Data Returned Here
    print("YEAR: {} ".format(yr))
    if yr:
        pass
    else:
        yr = template

    if len(yr) < len(template):
        for each in yr:
            for part in template:
                if each[0] == part[0]:
                    pass
                else:
                    yr = yr + (part,)
    else:
        pass

    mnth = sql_fin('month')
    mnth = db_query(mnth)  # Monthly Data Returned Here
    print("MONTH: {} ".format(mnth))

    wk = sql_fin('week')
    wk = db_query(wk)  # Weekly Data Returned Here
    print("WEEK: {} ".format(wk))

    data = {(name, n): [y, 0, 0] for name, n, y in yr}

    print("DATA:".format(data))
    for name, n, m in mnth:
        data[name, n][1] = m

    for name, n, w in wk:
        data[name, n][2] = w

    data = tuple(tuple([*k, *v]) for k, v in data.items())

    print("DATA: {}".format(data))
    return data
```

I tried to add a default template in but I did not do it well. Now the other numbers (monthly and weekly) are coming in but all yearly data is zeroed out.

What am I not seeing??

Compared to the template, if something like this returned:

```
(('ham', '0905', 3), ('Wind', '852', 4))
```

How can I ensure the other entries make it in without altering data

Comment: Can you please correct the padding?

Comment: Yea sorry Ill get it now

Comment: The double loop there is not doing what you expect. You can try printing `each` and `part` in every iteration to see what you are getting.

Comment: By the way, tuples are inmutables, so you are creating new tuples every time you try to do a change, you should use other container. If you need the output to be tuples swap it back at then end when all the changes are done.

Comment: I printed at the double loop and it looks right. I think I am overwriting the year data somewhere else. I know this is not the prettiest solution but I am a hundred tweaks in and trying not to have to re-write it all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using a defaultdict

```
from collections import defaultdict

def Main():
    yr_dict = defaultdict(int)
    template = (('ham', '0905'), ('Wind', '852'), ('Wash', '3292'), ('Chitt', '3367'))

    yr = sql_fin('year')
    yr = db_query(yr)  # Yearly Data Returned Here
    print("YEAR: {} ".format(yr))

    for a, b, c in yr:
        yr_dict[a + ":" + b] = c

    yr = tuple((a, b, yr_dict[a + ":" + b]) for a, b in template)

    mnth = sql_fin('month')
    mnth = db_query(mnth)  # Monthly Data Returned Here
    print("MONTH: {} ".format(mnth))

    wk = sql_fin('week')
    wk = db_query(wk)  # Weekly Data Returned Here
    print("WEEK: {} ".format(wk))

    data = {(name, n): [y, 0, 0] for name, n, y in yr}

    print("DATA:".format(data))
    for name, n, m in mnth:
        data[name, n][1] = m

    for name, n, w in wk:
        data[name, n][2] = w

    data = tuple(tuple([*k, *v]) for k, v in data.items())

    print("DATA: {}".format(data))
    return data
```

Comment: I'm getting a syntax error at `yr = ((a, b, yr_dict[a + ":" + b] for a, b in template))`

Comment: There was a missig parenthesis and a `tuple`

Comment: I caught the parenthesis, it is something else

Comment: The `tuple` keyword?

Comment: PyCharm is calling it a syntax error and pointing at the `for` statement

Comment: You are closing the parenthesis at the end, the missing one was before the `for`

Comment: @Joe If this answer solved your problem please select it as the accepted answer so that the question is marked as answered. If not please tell us what problems did you find.

Comment: I was never able to get over the syntax error. Your answer was mostly right, it was a defaultdict that I needed but the answer would not work for me

Comment: Did you check that the parenthesis you added matches the one I added? You wrote it wrong in the first comment. `yr = tuple((a, b, yr_dict[a + ":" + b]) for a, b in template)` is working properly on Python3.

Comment: Yeah, I did check that and still got the syntax error. I am on 3.6. I will look at it again tonight, if I am making a silly mistake I will mark it correct.

Comment: It's working on Python 3.5 on my machine. I'm replacing the SQL call for `yr = (('ham', '0905', 3), ('Wind', '852', 4))` as I can't do that SQL query but the rest is working perfectly and `yr` ends up being `(('ham', '0905', 3), ('Wind', '852', 4), ('Wash', '3292', 0), ('Chitt', '3367', 0))`.

Comment: Ok I remember now, after fixing the syntax your line `yr = tuple...`  was breaking bc it is expecting two values and I was passing more. The answer I ended up working in can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46774105/merge-multiple-lists-of-lists-based-on-template                    In this answer he initialized defaultdict like this: `joined_data = defaultdict([0, 0, 0].copy)` That allows me to create all the objects needed with the three default values. If you can get your answer to work like this I will accept it

Comment: You mean not having the `0`s in the template? I purpousely deleted them from there. The default dict with `int` as the default function already initiates them to 0. In your actual case using `[0, 0, 0].copy` as the default copy does the same but with the 3 arguments you are using now.