# Merge Multiple Lists of Lists Based on Template

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, tuples

I have 3 DB calls returning a tuple of tuples with a name, code and count like so:

`year = (('Fanklin Grand Isle', '5560', 1), ('Windham', '3457', 1))`

`month = (('Fanklin Grand Isle', '5560', 1), ('Chittendon', '3367', 1))`

`week = (('Fanklin Grand Isle', '5560', 1), ('Chittendon', '3367', 1))`

I need to merge these all together so that they will have the Name, code and count for yearly, monthly and weekly.

My problem is that if there is no record I need to insert the Name and code in AND a 0 value for the counts. The end product should be something like:

```
result = (('Windham', '0905', 1, 1, 0), ('Windsor Windham', '7852', 0, 0, 0), ('Washington', '3292', 0, 0, 0),
            ('Orleans Essex', '44072', 1, 1, 0), ('Addison', '2853', 0), ('Bennington', '3778', 0),
            ('Fanklin Grand Isle', '5560', 0, 0 0), ('Caledonia', '1992', 0, 0, 0),
            ('Rutland', '2395', 1, 0, 0), ('Chittendon', '3367', 1, 1, 0), ('Lamoille', '5229',0, 0 0))
```

I was trying to nest a loop to check if the name was present in the DB call and the template. IF if was append the DB value to the list, if not append 0

```
i = 0
for p in newlist:
    try:
        if p[0] == mlist[i][0]:
            print("HERE: {} {}".format(p[0], mlist[i][0]))
            p.append(mlist[i][-1])
            i += 1
        else:
            p.append(0)
    except IndexError:
        continue
```

This is appending the DB value but not the zero. I am sure there must be a better way to do this and get it to actually work.

***Edit***

Here is the updated code based on answers received. For me it is still replacing each `year` value with a 0.

DATA:

```
year = (('Fanklin Grand Isle', '5560', 1), ('Windham', '0905', 0), ('Windsor Windham', '7852', 0), ('Washington', '3292', 0), ('Orleans Essex', '44072', 0), ('Chittendon', '18028633367', 1), ('Addison', '12853', 0), ('Bennington', '3778', 0), ('Caledonia', '11992', 0), ('Rutland', '1895', 0), ('Chittendon', '18367', 0), ('Lamoille', '1809', 0), ('Windham', '180905', 0), ('Windsor Windham', '180852', 0), ('Waston', '18022623292', 0), ('Orleans Essex', '18072', 0), ('Addison', '1853', 0), ('Bennington', '1778', 0), ('Fanklin Grand Isle', '18560', 0), ('Caledonia', '180292', 0), ('Rutland', '195', 0), ('Lamoille', '18229', 0))

month = (('Fanklin Grand Isle', '5560', 1), ('Chittendon', '18028633367', 1))

week = (('Fanklin Grand Isle', '5560', 1), ('Chittendon', '18367', 1))
```

Code:

```
from collections import defaultdict
joined_data = defaultdict([0, 0, 0].copy)

for entry in year:
    # we create the default entry by calling the defaultdict with a key
    # and immediately grab the newly created list
    count = joined_data[(entry[0],entry[1])]
    # we swap *inplace* the value given by the DB query
    count[0] = entry[2]

# rinse and repeat with the rest of the data
for entry in month:
    count = joined_data[(entry[0], entry[1])]
    count[1] = entry[2]

for entry in week:
    count = joined_data[(entry[0], entry[1])]
    count[2] = entry[2]

# Finally we format the data to the required format
result = tuple(key+tuple(value) for key,value in joined_data.items() )
print(result)
```

Result:

`(('Fanklin Grand Isle', '5560', 0, 1, 1), ('Windham', '0905', 0, 0, 0), ('Windsor Windham', '7852', 0, 0, 0), ('Washington', '3292', 0, 0, 0), ('Orleans Essex', '1072', 0, 0, 0), ('Chittendon', '13367', 0, 1, 1), ('Addison', '2853', 0, 0, 0), ('Bennington', '1878', 0, 0, 0), ('Caledonia', '1992', 0, 0, 0), ('Rutland', '2395', 0, 0, 0), ('Lamoille', '5229', 0, 0, 0))`

Comment: Of course all those cities get a `0` for the year if the year-count is `0` in your `year` list. What output did you expect instead, and why?

Comment: Sorry tobias did not mean to edit your post, meant to edit mine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a way to deal with your issue using a `defaultdict` to avoid having to care about the missing entries :

```
year = (('Fanklin Grand Isle', '5560', 1), ('Windham', '3457', 1))
month = (('Fanklin Grand Isle', '5560', 1), ('Chittendon', '3367', 1))
week = (('Fanklin Grand Isle', '5560', 1), ('Chittendon', '3367', 1))

#I'm using a defaultdict to deal with the missing entries
from collections import defaultdict
joined_data = defaultdict([0,0,0].copy)

for entry in year:
    #we create the default entry by calling the defaultdict with a key
    #and immediately grab the newly created list
    count = joined_data[(entry[0],entry[1])]
    #we swap *inplace* the value given by the DB query
    count[0] = entry[2]

#rinse and repeat with the rest of the data
for entry in month:
    count = joined_data[(entry[0],entry[1])]
    count[1] = entry[2]

for entry in week:
    count = joined_data[(entry[0],entry[1])]
    count[2] = entry[2]

#Finally we format the data to the required format
result = tuple(key+tuple(value) for key,value in joined_data.items() )
print(result)
```

Output:

```
>>>(('Chittendon', '3367', 0, 1, 1), ('Fanklin Grand Isle', '5560', 1, 1, 1), ('Windham', '3457', 1, 0, 0))
```

Comment: This looks promising, I half tested it and it seems to be good. I will have a chance to fully test soon and if it works Ill mark this answer. Thanks!

Comment: this is still setting every year entry in the result to 0, even if there should be a value there.

Comment: @Joe How is this "setting every year entry to 0"? There are clearly some 1s for Franklin and Windham, same as for my results. Please edit your question and provide some complete and consistent input and output data.

Comment: Ill edit my question to reflect what I ran. I see that your output is correct but mine is off somehow

Comment: I added what I am running and the result so you can. Not sure how I am breaking it.

Comment: So it is normal for the names to be repeated. I am making three separate database queries for this data. so it will return year to date calls, then month to date, then week to date. the year should be the first value then month then week

Comment: There is no need to sum anything each db call returns in this format: `((city, code, number of calls` I need to merge the three different results to this format `city, code, ytd calls, mtd calls, week to date`

Comment: This overwrites previous entries. Note that there are duplicate cities in the `year` list. Try `count[0] += entry[2]` instead.

Comment: @jadsq   ...I feel...stupid... That was my problem :(

Comment: Last question. So what caused the repeated values was me trying to get the complete list. Cities that have had 0 calls will not return in the results but i need them in the list. How do I populate default values in the dict for all cities?

Comment: Every `city+city code` pair that appear in `year` *or* `month` *or* `weeks`  *will* be present in the result. To populate the dict with other pairs  with default values you just have to call `joined_data[(city_name,city_code)]` once and that will create a new entry with the default value.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand what you are trying to achieve, as your example input does not really match your output, but I think you can just use a list comprehension to construct the result, checking whether those items are in the `years`, `months` and `weeks` lists, and adding a `1` or `0` respectively:

```
>>> year = (('Fanklin Grand Isle', '5560', 1), ('Windham', '3457', 1))
>>> month = (('Fanklin Grand Isle', '5560', 1), ('Chittendon', '3367', 1))
>>> week = (('Fanklin Grand Isle', '5560', 1), ('Chittendon', '3367', 1))
>>> [(x[0], x[1], int(x in year), int(x in month), int(x in week)) for x in set(year + week + month)]
[('Chittendon', '3367', 0, 1, 1),
 ('Windham', '3457', 1, 0, 0),
 ('Fanklin Grand Isle', '5560', 1, 1, 1)]
```

If those counts can actually be different from `1`, you should first create a few dictionaries mapping the cities to their respective year/month/week counts, and then use a similar list comprehension as above:

```
>>> year_counts = {(name, code): count for (name, code, count) in year}
>>> month_counts = {(name, code): count for (name, code, count) in month}
>>> week_counts = {(name, code): count for (name, code, count) in week}
>>> all_cities = [(name, code) for (name, code, count) in set(year + month + week)]
>>> [(x[0], x[1], year_counts.get(x, 0), month_counts.get(x, 0), week_counts.get(x, 0)) for x in all_cities]
[('Chittendon', '3367', 0, 1, 1),
 ('Windham', '3457', 1, 0, 0),
 ('Fanklin Grand Isle', '5560', 1, 1, 1)]
```

Comment: I am trying to create a report which will display an incoming call count for each location, broken down by year to day, month to date, and week to date. The problem is that these are three separate db calls so I need to merge all together and if a location is missing insert the name and 0s

Comment: @Joe That much of the question was clear, but I gather that my first guess did not hit the spot yet. How is it now? If that's still not what you want, please try to clarify the question.

Comment: I need each result to be unique so I can email the report out to clients. So it should have the `name, code, yr count, month count, week count` format. Where each of these could change every week when I run the script

Comment: @Joe Ah, did not notice the dupes. You have to use a `set` in `all_cities`

Comment: Maybe the dict comprehensions are over my head but I cannot make sense of what you have posted

Comment: @Joe Those comprehensions just map the first two elements of the tuples to the last element, e.g. creating `{('Fanklin Grand Isle', '5560'): 1, ('Windham', '3457'): 1}`. You can then use those dicts to quickly get the counts for year/month/week in the final list comprehension.

Comment: Ok I think I am getting the gist of what you did. The problem is that my `week month year` results will not reflect all the cities. In my original post you can see the `result` is what I need. There are many more cities than will be returned in from the db call.

Comment: And even with the set it is still dumping duplicates

Comment: @Joe Well, then maybe you should base the list comprehension on whatever list of all the cities you get from the DB instead of `all_cities` I created from the three lists.